# bridge adapter is not being created after restore default vmware

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Hi  I don't have connection when I set my connection to bridge, NAT works perfect but bridge not.

I've uninstalled VMWARE many times and nothing happens...

I've tried deleting all conections and leave only bridge

I've restored to default settings

I've tried changing that "automatic" from bridge to my wireles network called Intel(R) Centrino(R) wireleness-N 1030

I've created a new network "Host or NAT" so that way a new adapter is being created, but as soon as I change it to bridge, that adapter disappear

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED if anyone have a problem like this it's maybe because your wireless network doesn't have support for the current operative system.